# Splitting a string then accessing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New to Javascript and jQuery, so I assume this is a pretty simple question.

I have a date I want to split into a string, then print out the array.

```
var date = "12/10/2010";
var dateArray = date.split(/);

$('#printbox').html($(dateArray[0]));
```

`<span id="printbox"></span>`

---

Edit: The question is, how can I split "12/10/2010" into an array like this:

```
Array[0] = 12
Array[1] = 10
Array[3] = 2010
```

And how do I print them to HTML?

Comment: What's your question...what's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first parameter to the [string.split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function should be a string or regex:

```
var date = "12/10/2010";
var dateArray = date.split("/");

// dateArray[0] == 12
// dateArray[1] == 10
// dateArray[2] == 2010

// Now use the array to print out whichever way you want (jQuery.html(values))...
```

Comment: This seems nice, the Array is just not outputting to HTML.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does putting the first element of the array into a jQuery construct do? Does it print out all values of the array? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: I realize this is a carryover from the question, but it doesn't make sense to wrap `dataArray[0]` in a jQuery object. :o) Better would be to do a `.join()`, like `.html( dateArray.join(', ') )`.

Comment: @stjowa - if you look at the example of the OP, the HTML markup has a div with id `printbox`, the jQuery simply sets the contents of that div with the passed in string. See [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: @danixd - it was taken from your example. The jQuery [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function will populate the selected elements with the passed in html.

Comment: it creates DOM elements out of the string. The call to $('#printbox')'s html is setting the inner html of the #printbox element to the month in the date array. see more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @Oded - I was referring to $(dateArray[0]). This would have translated to $(12) and didn't make sense as **patrick dw** described. But, I see it got removed.

Comment: @stjowa - Fair enough, guess I didn't spot the wrapping of the array in jQuery first time around.

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = "12/10/2010";
var dateArray = date.split('/');

$('#printbox').html(dateArray[0]); // it displays 12 in printbox
$('#printbox').html(dateArray[1]); // it displays 10 in printbox
$('#printbox').html(dateArray[2]); // it displays 2010 in printbox
```

Comment: Each subsequent call to `.html()` will overwrite the previous.

Comment: Of course ! It was to help him to make a choice. It was obvious for me but you're right, not for everybody...

Answer (score 1):

For splitting you were almost there :)

```
var dateArray = date.split("/");
```

If you want to use jQuery you could use the [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method.

```
$.each(dateArray, function(index, value) { 
  // print out here
});
```

This constructs a loop that iterates over the elements in your array. You can access this element by the `value` variable.

Comment: It works perfect. I just used it in my jquery mobile project. I have spitted values 
<code>
 var fromService = data.split(";");
        $.each(fromService, function (index, value) {
            // print out here
            $('#townlist li:last-child').removeClass();
            $("#townlist").append("<li class='ui-last-child'><a href='#' class='ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r'>ITEM</a></li>");
        });
        
        $("#townlist").listview("refresh");
</code>

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = "12/10/2010";
var dateArray = date.split('/');

// dateArray => ['12', '10', '2010']
```

If you want to use jQuery there is an each function that you can use:

```
$.each(dateArray, function (index, value) {
    $('#printbox').append(value);
});
```

There is also a .forEach method in newer browsers:

```
dateArray.forEach(function (value) {
    document.getElementById('printbox').
        appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
});
```

Older browsers can have this method via the Array.prototype:

```
if (!(Array.prototype.forEach === 'function')) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function (fn) {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i += 1) {
            fn(this[i]);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "12/10/2010";
var dateArray = date.split(/\//); // have to quote regular expressions with /

document.write; // this does nothing

$('#printbox').html(dateArray[2] + '-' + dateArray[0] + '-' + dateArray[1]); // do what you want here. The code I provided should print 2010-12-10
```

Comment: I don't see the point of regex in `.split()`, doing .split('/') is simpler and does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "12/10/2010";
var dateArray = date.split('/');

var year = dateArray.splice(2,1);
dateArray[3] = year;
```

should give you

```
Array[0] = 12
Array[1] = 10
Array[3] = 2010
```

But why you need the year in the fourth key I don't know. (also removes from the third so you don't end up with two years)